# Find number and move to end of line with notepad++ & RegEx

Tags: notepad++, regex

I need to move numeric character from line begging to end of line in sample below. I'm planning to use `RegEx` and Notepad++. To find number I use `[1-9]+` expression. But how to select this number and move to end of line?

Current:

```
 1 #define AAA
 2 #define BBB
 123 #define CCC
```

Should be:

```
 #define AAA 1
 #define BBB 2
 #define CCC 123
```

Comment: [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
and [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used N++ v7.2.2

Ctrl+H --> Replace tab
Find what: (^)(\s+)?(\d+)(\s+)(#define)(\s+)([^\r\n]+)?(\r\n|$)
Replace with: \1\5\6\7\4\3\8
Wrap around: checked
Search Mode: Regular expression